# How to check if mms:// rtsp:// rtp:// anf rtmp:// links are available and streaming data?

Tags: c#, .net, streaming

I have no clue how to check if `mms:// rtsp:// rtp://  rtmp://` links are available and streaming data...

Any clue where I can start on with that?

I need something like

```
bool IsMediaURLAlive(string url)
{
    // main code ... 
    return false;
}
```

Any clue?

Comment: `1` no way other than attempt to start actual streaming `2` protocol is followed by "://", not ":\\" `3` you might want to at least check host/port for availability for generic TCP connection.

Comment: @RomanR. I mean how I can do it remotely.

Comment: "attempt to start actual streaming" *remotely*

Comment: @RomanR. Cool! Any idea about the code? How it could be implemented?

Comment: Find a library that does streaming and try to feed an URL there, check for errors. There is no way you otherwise (without a library) can implement the method you quoted above without adding thousands lines of code (which you certainly won't get there ready-for-use in someone's answer).

Comment: @RomanR. Thanks man!!! Have a free beer always!! :)